# How to open a file using argparse.FileType only if a condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using python 3 argparse. I have multiple files passed as `argparse.FileType` which I use to write some data. I want to check some conditions and open those files only if they are met. However argparse opens them immediately, and they are created even if I exit with error code.

```
import argparse
from sys import exit

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--condition', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('out1', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
    parser.add_argument('out2', type=argparse.FileType('w'))

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.condition:
        print('ERROR: please use --condition')
        exit(2)

    args.out1.write('hello\n')
    args.out2.write('world\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run this example without passing the `--condition` argument, it will still create 2 new files. I don't want to create them in that case. Can I do that without passing filename and opening the files manually?

Comment: If you want to do more specific handling, don't use `FileType`; do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to just accept the filenames as the default string type, and open the files later.

http://bugs.python.org/issue13824 (`argparse.FileType opens a file and never closes it`) implements a `FileContext` type, one that operates like `FileType` except that it returns a `context` that can be used later as:

```
with args.input() as f:
    f.read()
    etc
```

But doing filename checking while parsing, without actually opening or creating a file, is not trivial.  And handling `stdin/out` which should not be closed adds a complication.

In that bug issue, Steven Bethard, the `argparse` developer, notes that `FileType` was intended for quick scripts, not for larger projects where proper opening and closing files matters.